# media app takes too long to buffer

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I have an application that loads steaming media from a server via shout cast (i was given the current android application code from a client. It was developed by a previous developer).

In Android Studio, i see in the logcat a message that there are too many activities on main thread. this happens when i select a radio channel to stream.

How can i move this to a background thread and get this off the main thread???
a majority of users say the app takes to long to load the stream and then times out on most phones (my OnePlus One Android phone here in the US never times out. it always loads -- but it does take A LONG TIME truthfully).

In general, if some one can give me some pointers that would be great.
I have read about using AsyncTask, but I am unfamiliar with how to do that and I fear it would result in a major re-write of the application.

Thanks!!!

ironmantis7x

Comment: `I am unfamiliar with [AsyncTask]`. The easiest solution would be to start by reading the documentation for AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Create your own class that extends AsyncTask
Give the following generics Params(URL) Progress(In int format) Result(Long)

In this example they are downloading multiple files.
The idea is that it is running on a different thread:

```
   private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Then to use:

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

If for some reason it still takes to long, you can tell android that this thread is importent, and Android will try and give it more time to run.

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
```

Comment: I will post the code from the app that is in place now to show everyone what is going on for clarity.

Comment: Sure thing, I've added anouter way you can try and make this event faster.

Comment: No, you would add that line it the beginning of the doInBackground method.
I suggest you have a read about what are threads and how they work.
In short, android like any machine works with threads, each thread has its own goal, you processor can run only one thread at a time, so what we do is create a new thread and the OS gives each thread a number of mill secs (less) to run, by saying this thread has max priority, you say, "Hi! android! this one is important! give it more time!"